# nestjs convert interfaces to graphql classes

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I have a project build on Rest api, and it uses interfaces. I need to convert it to Graphql classes. Is there a readymade package or tool to help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code-first strategy for GraphQL. You should create a class for each interface and annotate it with `ObjectType`, `InputType` and `ArgsType`, you can check the documentation [for ObjectType](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#object-types), [for InputType](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/mutations) and [for ArgsType](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/resolvers#class-inheritance). If you use polymorphism you should check `Unions` and `Interfaces`, both are available at the nestjs documentation

Comment: thanks for answering, I was thinking of ready-made tool but it seems there is nothing